# Want to know what did I do wrong with this line integral along the helix C

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Suppose $\overrightarrow F(x,y,z) = -y\overrightarrow i + x\overrightarrow j + 0.5\overrightarrow k$ and $C$ is the helix given by $x(t) = 5 cos (t), y(t)=5sin(t),z(t)=t/5$ for $0 \leq t\leq6\pi$. Find the line integral.

So, here is what I did.
$\int_C\overrightarrow F \bullet d\overrightarrow r) = \int_0^{6\pi}(-5\sin (t)+5\cos (t)+0.5)(\sqrt {25\sin^2 t+25\cos^2 t+1/25})$

I have this gut feeling that I messed up the $r't$ part of $\int_a^b f(r(t))|r't|dt $ but I can't quite figure the reason out.

Comment: The thing is that the answer I got was (3(sqrt2)(sqrt313)pi)/5 = 47.16157 and that wasn't the answer.

Comment: Your formula is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $\overrightarrow F(x,y,z) = -y\overrightarrow i + x\overrightarrow j + 0.5\overrightarrow k$ and $C$ is the helix given by $x(t) = 5 cos (t), y(t)=5sin(t),z(t)=t/5$ for $0 \leq t\leq6\pi$. Take

$\int_C\overrightarrow F \bullet d\overrightarrow r) = \int_0^{6\pi}(-5\sin (t), 5\cos (t), 0.5). (-5 sin(t), 5\cos(t), 1/5)dt$ = $\int_0^{6\pi} (25  + 1/10 )dt$

$=(25  + 1/10 ) 6\pi.$

NB: The formula you have written for the line integral is NOT correct. There should not be any absolute value sign.

Comment: I got the formula from https://users.math.msu.edu/users/maccomb1/ss15/234/ch16/ch16-filled.pdf page 8.

Thank you for the kind answer. I was stuck for it for like last 4 hours lol.

Comment: @Jason: to elaborate on Peer's comment: there are two different types of line integrals; a _scalar_ and a _vector_.  The vector line integral is defined as $\int{\vec{F}\,dr}=\int{\vec{F}(\vec{r}(t))|\vec{r}'(t)|\,dt}$ (2.4 in the linked notes).  The scalar is defined as (note the vector symbol!) $\int{\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}}=\int{\vec{F}(\vec{r}(t))\cdot\vec{r}'(t)\,dt}$ instead (2.8 in the linked notes).  In case it isn't clear, the names come from what the quantities are: the vector line integral is a vector and the scalar line integral is a scalar.

Comment: I see where you are confused. Look at the def again. Take a look at def 2.8.

Comment: @JacobManaker: Thank you for additional information. I guess I should be much careful now about vector and scalara integral. I was really having so much question marks on my brain cause I didn't think that the formula I was using was the wrong one.

Comment: Kudos to kind hearted men. Thanks to both of ya!

Comment: We are glad that we could help.